# How to generate and hex encode a ED25519 keypair using openssl 3.0 c++

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

So far I can do the following. But I have no idea if it is working because I can't see the keys. I am planning on extracting them into a char array and storing them In a struct. So I need the full encoded byte array for the private and public keys.

I think I have it working partially for RSA. But I can't figure out how to use ED22519.

```
static bool GenerateEncryptionKeys(ofstream *file)
        {
            EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
            EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;

            ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);
            if (ctx)
            {
                if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(ctx) > 0)
                {
                    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(ctx, 2048) > 0)
                    {
                        if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(ctx, &pkey) > 0)
                        {
                            print("All good");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
return.
```

Comment: Please provide a clear statement of what you've done, and what about it does not work.   Asking _"how to use the ED22519"_  indicates that you are closer to being at the _study the documentation_ phase, which should come before the coding stage of your project.  More detailed info on the specific problem is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I solved it.

```cpp
static bool GenerateEncryptionKeys()
        {
            EVP_PKEY *my_pkey = nullptr;
            EVP_PKEY_CTX *my_ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_ED25519, nullptr);
            EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(my_ctx);
            EVP_PKEY_keygen(my_ctx, &my_pkey);

            std::size_t pub_key_allocated_length;
            EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key(my_pkey, NULL, &pub_key_allocated_length);

            unsigned char *public_key = new unsigned char[pub_key_allocated_length];
            EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key(my_pkey, public_key, &pub_key_allocated_length);

            std::size_t pkey_allocated_length;
            EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key(my_pkey, NULL, &pkey_allocated_length);

            unsigned char *private_key = new unsigned char[pkey_allocated_length];
            EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key(my_pkey, private_key, &pkey_allocated_length);
            WriteEncryptionKeys(convertToString((const char *)private_key, pkey_allocated_length), convertToString((const char *)public_key, pub_key_allocated_length));
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Not a big issue now that you have what you need, but your solution clearly indicates you were looking for a C++ solution but the question was originally tagged as C.  I will edit the tags there.  fwiw, This question/answer could be useful to others, Accept the answer when you are able.  (Hollow check mark)